# JSON returns an HTML result

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, json

I'm using dataTable and I'm having the Json parse error. Here is my code:

```
jQuery(function($){
         $('#allusers').dataTable({
             "sAjaxSource": document.URL+"/allusers.php"
         });

        $.ajax({
            url: document.URL+"/allusers.php",
            success: function(data){
                alert (data);
            }
        });
    });
```

So inserted the `$.ajax` part so that I could see the data being returned. (Well I could also see it using firebug, just wanna make sure) and the response that I am getting is the HTML code instead of the JSON object.

here is the snippet of allusers.php:

```
$dataArr['aaData'] = Array();
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$numrows = $res->num_rows;
$output = array('iTotalRecords' => $numrows, "iTotalDisplayRecords" => 10, "aaData" => array() );
if ($res = $mysqli->query($query)){
    while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $r = Array();
        foreach($row as $key=>$value){
            $r[] = $value;
        }
        $output['aaData'][] = $r;
    } 
} else 
    die(mysql_errno());
$output['err'] = 'hello';
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($output);
exit();
```

I already tried `var_dump($r)` to check the contents of $output and I don't see a problem with it.

So the result that I'm getting is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="home">
<head>
<title>User List</title>
...
```

it basically returns the html content of the whole page.
Is the problem within the javascript or php?
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: doesn't make sense unless you have includes not shown or are running this through some sort of MVC framework as a view

Comment: try to put the given url into a browser and check what happens (I mean the js generated url: `document.URL+"/allusers.php"`)

Comment: @charlietfl hi, I'm using EdenPHP MVC framework. What includes may have an effect on this?

Comment: @jsc it just displays the page. I tried to use the allusers.php outside the framework I'm using and it worked just fine.

Comment: well if you are treating this as a view could be ouputing the main header template. I know nothing about edenPHP. This needs to be sent directly from a controller with nothing else sent

Comment: @charlietfl the allusers.php is actually a separate php file, it's placed inside the directory of the controller but it is not part of the controller.

Comment: @charlietfl try to change to this: `document.URL+"allusers.php"`, if it comes with this value `http://example.com//allusers.php` and the router  manage to load the default controller (instead of a 404?) caused by the extra slash, should explain the problem.

Comment: @jsc is right.... most probably there is error in your allusers.php file, so that instead of returning json file its returning html page with error message..... If you are using any MVC then for AJAX call use blank template instead of default master template which have header, banner etc html code...

Comment: why aren't you just using a controller? What's the point of the framework if you are by passing it?

Comment: use dataType: "application/json", and method: "POST"

Comment: @charlietfl I'm going to use DataTables for outputting rows from db.

Comment: @jsc tried it, still doesn't work. :/

Comment: my last idea, if you using apache and fancy sort urls: in your .htaccess file check for this line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` just after the `RewriteEngine on`, if it not exists put it in.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your PHP framework respects requested datatypes, but you could start by requesting JSON specifically. Either specify:

```
$.ajax({
        url: document.URL+"/allusers.php",
        dataType: "application/json",
        success: function(data){
            alert (data);
        }
    });
```

or use the jquery json shortcut:

```
$.getJSON("url", data, callbackFuntion);
```

The default for the $.ajax() method is to intelligently guess the output, so it seems weird it doesn't pick up on your content-type.

My last idea would be that you specified php headers and footers globally somehow, so they are added to your output?

Comment: tried it, I also added error: function(data) now it alerts [object][object]

Comment: ok, then we're getting somewhere, you have an array of 2 objects. they might be json. What's in them if you inspect or console.log() them?  and most importantly, was that output from the succes() or the error() callback function?

Answer (score 0):

I've already fixed this problem. Since I'm using a MVC, I put the function in the controller then just added a code like this:

```
if (isset($_GET["var"]))
    function();
```

also I removed the 
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

I don't know why, but when I removed that it worked. Thanks all for pitching in your ideas. :)